# When drawing two vector shapes, why does the second one not update with the correct foreground colour?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, shapes

I just drew one black rectangle. I then changed the foreground colour to red and drew a second one on a new layer, but this remained black. I had to go into the fill options and change it to the red colour I desired, but I'm wondering why it was not enough simply to change the foreground colour before drawing the new shape?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it is simply a decision by Adobe to have the shape fill color independent of the foreground/background color. I'm not sure the motivation, but agree that I'd rather they were in sync.

Comment: Yes, I guess this is right. Weird change to introduce, but I suppose I'll get used to it. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

It behaved this way because you changed the foreground colour while the shape was selected, so it only changed the colour for that selected object.

If nothing is selected and you change the foreground colour (or stroke) then shapes created from then on will be of that colour.

EDIT

The above method would work on older versions but in more recent versions such as CC and CS6, shape colour is not affected by the foreground or background colours. When the shape tool is selected colour options are at the top.
[image]

Comment: That doesn't work for me. Testing it then, I created a red shape, deselected everything and changed tools, changed the foreground to blue and then went to the shape tool and it created another red shape. It seems to remember the last fill color, even if the foreground has changed.

Comment: are you using Photoshop CC?

Comment: yes, I'm on CC, but the same functionality happens for CS6 and CS4, (just tested) so it is nothing new.